# Image.setIcon(Parameters) Is not refreshing the Label

Tags: java, swing, icons, refresh, set

I'm working with Java Swing in the making of an Online Chess(Client-Server), I have been able to make the chessTable form wonderfully with no trouble, but in the lobby I'm showing the user's Avatar, the problem is that, the user is able to change his avatar through the server, but when ever I call the `setIcon` of the new image, it wont refresh it.

Explanation:

The users start with a default image(Avatar.jpg) downloadead from the server,if he changes it, the server sends to the client the new image he chose with the same name of the previous one, so it gets replaced. But when ever i call `setIcon` of this new image(after the download), it wont do anything and the Label stick to show the first image he ever set. I'm checking the folder and the image are being sent form the server to the client with out problems, and the only way for me to make the client refresh the Avatar is by closing and opening the app. Any ideas?, I tried reprint every random thing I could find still no solution, and the labels refresh by a clickedListener.
I use this line to set the image:

```
this.JLProfilePic.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/View/Images/avatar.jpg")));
```

Edit1: I'm not working with a `JApplet`, still I don't have any idea of where the problem might be originated, since Im able to change the Label Icon to any image but when ever I try to change the Icon to Avatar, it still shows the previous one even if in the folder you can see that Avatar.jpg is not the same, it changed for a new one.

Edit2: Well I still haven't found any solutions for this, I supose might be true or not, since i setIcon once, the image is saved at the cache when ever the program re access to the same image it goes to the cache instead of checking again the source of the file. Not sure but is the only Logic I can make.

Comment: Is this a JApplet? If so, it sounds like a cache issue. I'm not 100% sure, but for some instances getting the Image first via `ImageIO.read(...)` before creating the ImageIcon has helped with this, but I'm not sure if that's the case in this particular circumstance. I'm awaiting better and more expert opinion on this.

Comment: I guess, the issue raised here, can very much be solved, by the first example, provided in the Tutorials for [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/simple.html), once done downloading, only then will it show it to the user, I had tried once opening a URL in `JTextPane`, with same issues, seems like `SwingWorker` is the answer to this issue too :-) Moreover, the issue appears to me, related to [EDT - Event Dispatch Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html), that you really not updating your GUI on the EDT.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

Image img = ImageIO.read(new URL("http:\Server_IP:Port\image.jpg"));

setIconImage(img);

Comment: Hi, thx for the answer. There are 2 problems with what you said:
1. What Im triying to change is a JLabel so I cant actually use setIconImage since that is for the window.
2. When the client downloads the image from the server its placed in the folder Images, so I dont actually need to read the image from an URL since its a JPG file placed in the folder of the proyect.